# firefox browser in mobile view is giving 504 gateway timeout response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, firefox, user-agent, geckodriver

I am trying to debug an issue where in web Firefox browser responsive mobile view when i am logged in https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/home by either method google login or email login, the page loads successfully one time however do not load again on refresh, or visiting any other page like https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/contests.

I tried and checked following things -

- The apis are giving 504 gateway timeout response.
- The issue is only reproducible in Firefox browsers tried almost all versions, not reproducible in chrome, brave, edge browsers.
- The issue is resolved in mobile view when the user agent is removed from the request.
- The response is not reproducible when importing the 504 responded api to postman.
- The issue is also not reproducible when in local angular dev setup.